# Where is a Windows Service project's exe built to?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a Windows Service project in VS.NET 2010.  For some reason, when I build, I don't see the EXE.  There is just

```
myapp.vshost.exe
```

there should be a

```
myapp.exe
```

The project settings are:

```
Target Framework: .NET Framework 4
Output type: Windows Application
```

Another thing I noticed is the bin\debug folder does not have any of the referenced DLLs.

Any idea where a non vshost EXE isn't being built?

Comment: Do you get build errors? What does the output window say where it was build or why it wasn't?

Comment: No build errors.  Each line of the output window starts with myapp.vshost.exe following by "Loaded:..." with the DLL that was loaded.

Comment: Where is the "Output Path" under the Build tab in settings say?

Comment: \bin\debug of the project folder.

Answer (score 2):

The vshost process is a helper process that allows Visual Studio to examine the process of your program while it's running, mainly for debugging purposes.

Your actual binary should be in the same directory as the vshost binary, which should be under `bin/Debug`, starting from the directory of your project.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was settings in the solution file, not the project file.  The solution had the Windows Service set to build as an x64 while everything else was set to "Any CPU".  After changing the WinService to build as "Any CPU", it now outputs the EXE.